# ¿Como realizar una accion cuando dejas de escribir en un JText Field en Java Swing ? (algo como onChange de Java script)

Tags: java, java-swing, netbeans-8.2

Tengo un JText Field donde se puede digitar el monto de un producto y quiero llamar a una función  después de llenar el JText Field  para poder 
así convertir el valor ingresado en moneda.

No encontre algo parecido en los evento de Key e  usado keyPressed , Keyreleased pero los dos funcionan como un onKeyUp.

alguien sabe como puedo hacer esto ?

No se que código mostrar así que pongo la forma en la que convierto el valor en moneda:

> ```
> String numCadena = "";
>    if (txtValorCompra.getText() == "" || txtValorCompra.getText() == null){
>        numCadena = "0.00";
>    }else{
>        numCadena = txtValorCompra.getText();
>    }
>    int numEntero = Integer.parseInt(numCadena);
> ```

```
   double monto = numEntero;
   NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.getDefault());
   txtValorCompra.setText(nf.format(monto));
```

Comment: [Esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31955193/how-to-start-a-function-after-stop-typing-in-a-jtextfield-in-java) te podría ayudar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una buena manera o forma de realizar una **acción** cuando dejas de escribir en el **JTextField** sería utilizar el **evento de ganar o perder el Foco** con la interfaz **FocusListener** y el respectivo método **[addFocusListener()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addFocusListener(java.awt.event.FocusListener))** perteneciente a **java.awt.Component** el cual llama a esa **acción**.

```
txtValorCompra.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
              //que hacer cuando ganamos el foco
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                //que hacer cuando se pierda el foco
                String numCadena = "";
                if (txtValorCompra.getText().trim().equals("")) {
                    numCadena = "0.00";
                } else {
                    numCadena = txtValorCompra.getText();
                }
                double numEntero = Double.parseDouble(numCadena);
                area.setText(String.valueOf(numEntero));
            }
        });
```

---

**Te dejo un ejemplo:**

```
public class JTextFieldTest extends JFrame {

    public JTextFieldTest() {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        this.setBounds(300, 300, 350, 300);
        JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
        JTextField txtValorCompra = new JTextField(20);

        txtValorCompra.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                String numCadena = "";
                if (txtValorCompra.getText().trim().equals("")) {
                    numCadena = "0.00";
                } else {
                    numCadena = txtValorCompra.getText();
                }
                double numEntero = Double.parseDouble(numCadena);
                area.setText(String.valueOf(numEntero));
            }
        });

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel();

        label.setText("Valor: ");
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(txtValorCompra);
        this.add("North", panel);
        this.add("South", area);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JTextFieldTest jt = new JTextFieldTest();
        jt.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jt.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! funciono

Comment: Me alegra haberte ayudado. :)

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto :

```
txtValorCompra.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
   //Lo que desees u ocupes hacer, este es un metodo similar a onchange en JS.
})
```

Saludos.

Comment: Eso en donde lo pondria ? dentro de un void funcion(){ } ?  o dentro de un evento ?